# How can I display an Azure Monitoring Dashboard without / with simple authenticating?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I want to display my Azure Dashboard on a big screen in the office, but obviously not login at the big screen with my personal account.

How can I access an Azure Monitoring Dashboard in read-only mode without having the dashboard computer using my personal credentials? Maybe with a token or http auth?

Comment: Why is there a constraint that there be no dedicated user? That would be the absolute simplest way to accomplish this.

Comment: Good question. - 1) I was looking for alternative solutions to creating a service user, because I knew that would be an option. 2) saving the additional cost for dedicated AD users. 3) I thought a dashboard service user might not have MFA enabled anyways; therefore a http auth solution _could_ be okay. But maybe you're right and one should just go for creating a service user, @WaitingForGuacamole (awesome username!).

Comment: It feels like a dedicated user would work more cleanly, as the Azure portal has its own way of getting that token through its own authentication flow - trying to hack a token into that would be rather difficult and very brittle, IMO. Also, I believe that it's possible in AD to make MFA optional for users with certain GPO applied?

Comment: Yes, disabling a user's MFA in the AD is possible. I think I'll modify the question and remove the restriction. It makes much more sense to keep the question open, as then we would at least have a valid answer listed here. In case anyone has a hack later, that would still be possible to be added here. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Done @WaitingForGuacamole - feel free to post your correct answer here :)

Comment: posted, if you'd like to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to run an Azure portal dashboard unattended, getting a token inserted into their page won't really be effective (*if* you can get it to work, it'll be brittle).

I'd recommend a dedicated AD account, which replicates to Azure AD. Grant that user privileges to the dashboard.

Then, log in on that machine with that user, log in to the Azure portal, again with that user, and display your dashboard.

You should be able to make the last part (especially with a cached token) run at startup. The worst you should have to do is periodically go to that machine and re-authenticate that user against Azure.